# Hibernate JPA foreign key no parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

when testing my entities i get the error 
foreign key no parent; FKF7EC361BFEA0E826 table: DEVICE_DEVICE_PRESETS
i'm testing by creating the entities in my device class constructor
the error happens when i don't create a stored preset entity and add it to my 
device preset entity. if i create the stored preset entity and add it to my device entity the code runs fine.

(1)-the error happens when stored preset entity is linked through an explicit foreign key column as shown below (stored_preset_num)

(2)- the error does not happen when  the entities share the same primary keys values

can someone please help me understand why when linked just by a foreign key it enforces that the entity is present instead of just enforcing the relationship?
why do i need to create the stored preset entity with (1) but not (2)

```
DEVICE

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id",referencedColumnName="device_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="node_id",referencedColumnName="node_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="instance_id",referencedColumnName="instance_id")
})
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   private List<DevicePreset> devicePresets;
```

```
DEVICE PRESETS
@ManyToOne
private Device device;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({   @JoinColumn(name="stored_preset_num",referencedColumnName=" stored_preset_num",insertable=false,updatable=false)
 })
private StoredPreset storedPreset;
```

STORED PRESET

```
@OneToOne
private DevicePreset devicePreset;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go again. Your mapping is wrong. In a bidirectional association, one side is the owner side, and contains the mapping (or chooses to use the default mapping by not using any JoinTable or JoinColun annotation), and the other MUST be marked as the inverse side of the other, using the `mappedBy` attribute. So the mapping should be :

In a bidirectional one to many association, you don't have the choice: the many side MUST be the owner side.

So the mapping should be:

DEVICE:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "device")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<DevicePreset> devicePresets;
```

DEVICE PRESETS:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id",referencedColumnName="device_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="node_id",referencedColumnName="node_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="instance_id",referencedColumnName="instance_id")
})
private Device device;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="stored_preset_num",referencedColumnName=" stored_preset_num")
private StoredPreset storedPreset;
```

STORED PRESET

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "storedPreset")
private DevicePreset devicePreset;
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why i get this error with the above changes?  broken column mapping for: devicePreset.storedPreset of: xxx.devices.xxx.entity.StoredPreset

Comment: Try with just a JoinColumn annotation as in my edited answer. Otherwise, ask another question, specifying the full mapping and the full stack trace of the exception you get.